# Cannot render links in text

Tags: playframework

I am trying to show some text from database which contains bold, links etc.

```
#{verbatim}
    <p>
    ${journal.content}<br />
    </p>
#{/verbatim}
```

Well, it does not render links as it should do. For instance if I put this in DB:

```
hello <a href="http://www.google.ro">google</a>
```

it renders it plain like you see here. But if I put `<strong>hello</strong>` it succesfully makes it bold.

Do you see any reason why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

Solved (found the cause).

Seems that, I was saving the content trough tiny_mce control and it puts `&lt;` in DB instead of `<` and so on.

To save html code, I had to apply [this](http://my.opera.com/Contrid/blog/2007/05/03/tinymce-insert-html-cod) solution.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to do `${journal.content?.raw()}` (without the `verbatim` tag) ?